# Linker cannot find exe file

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015

In x86 mode I can successfully build my solution (I'm using VS2015 and the project is in C++). But when I switch to x64 and try to build I'm getting:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:...\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Drawing_SDI\x64\Debug\Drawing_SDI.exe'

How is it possible that linker is looking for exe file? Isn't linker supposed to actually build exe from .obj files?

I'm confused. Help needed.

Comment: This can happen if the file is still running as well. Be sure the application is NOT running!

Comment: @duDE defo not running

Comment: Is the file there? Can you delete/rename it?

Comment: What is your platform toolset? Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Make sure the Application Experience service is started and not set to disabled

Comment: @Alan How/where can I set Application Experience?

Comment: @SimonKraemer No, the file isn't even there. Cleaning, rebuilding etc didn't help.

Comment: Winkey+R and on the window type "services.msc"

Comment: @Alan Hi, I've did that, there is no such process called Application Experience. I'm on Win10, with VS2015 Ultimate.

Comment: If it is set to "Manual", I believe VS will start it.

Comment: Ok, you might need to check this then: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx

Comment: @Alan Ok, one of possible causes of this error LNK1104 is listed: "file doesn't exist". And in my case file doesn't exist. I'm asking, why would linker complain about file not existing? Isn't linker supposed to build exe file?

Comment: The building process is actually a 3 step process. Preprocessor directives translation, compiling and then linking. Are you using an external library?

Comment: @Alan yes, building process is a 3 step process but linker is not linking with exe but creates exe, am I correct?

Comment: @Alan No, I'm not using any third party library

Comment: On the Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input tab of the project’s properties, there is an Additional Dependencies property. Try changing this property from \path\to\.lib to "\path\to\.lib"  with quotes, please.

Comment: @Alan, I'm sorry but I'm lost, I can of course open and find that tab, but path to which lib am I supposed to provide? I'm not using any third party libs, this is pure MFC project.

Comment: I'm just trying to go through all possibilities. Still looking, though.

Comment: Try resetting the Win32 and x64 compiler

Comment: @Alan how would I go about resetting compiler?

Comment: Could you please try these steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms185328.aspx They will help setting a proper environment for x64, hopefully this may suffice.

Comment: @Alan I did those steps, no joy. Still getting the same error. Why would linker try to find exe? It doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't indeed. The linker works with object files.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this problem? I just now created clean MFC project, changed build to x64 and have been able to successfully build it, so I'm really befuddled as to why I cannot simply build the one I'm on at the moment which is also just pure MFC, no third libs, nothing.

Comment: @Alan, maybe I'm on something, when in linker's output file field I've changed so it outputs to the build directory it does build that application. Something is wrong with linkers directories settings, although I never did anything with those settings. Any ideas what next?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100690/discussion-between-alan-and-there-is-nothing-we-can-do).